# Is there a way to config MySQL Connector J driver to insert empty string as 0 to decimal/integer field?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have a requirement to upgrade company's db legacy system from MySQL ver 4.1 to ver 5.5 ,I currently found out that if i insert empty string to decimal/integer field via java program ,It will throw exception but if i write the same statement and insert it directly via mysql command line the record will be inserted normally(the empty field will become 0),so this lead me to think that there are some problem with jdbc driver , is driver enforce some rule upon statement before pass it to db? i really dont want to re-write the old program to support this change.

thx in advance for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign value null not empty string.

You are changing your DB version so all codes may support. So you have to change

Comment: yep, that is one posibility but that required me to re-write old code, are there anyway to just config JDBC/MySQL without touching the old program at all?